# How to demonstrate that $x^TMx = x^TM^Tx$

Tags: matrices

I got a problem in mathematics.

I have a $q\times q$ matrix $M$

$$M=\pmatrix{m_{11} & m_{12} & \cdots & m_{1q}\\
             m_{21} & m_{22} & \cdots & m_{2q}\\
             \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
            m_{q1} & m_{q2} & \cdots & m_{qq}}$$
and

$x= ( 1\ 2\ \cdots\ p)$

and I want to demonstrate that :

$$x^TMx   =   x^TM^Tx$$

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Try to use $LaTeX$ to format your equations. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First of all $x$ has to be $q\times1$ vector. I am assuming that in my answer.

Secondly $$(x^TMx)^T=x^TM^Tx$$
Since $x^TMx$ is a scalar, its transpose is same as itself.